# UNIX - Prompt user for input inside remote SSH

Tags: bash, unix, ssh, sh, remote-server

When I login to a remote server using SSH, I'm trying to ask the user for input on whether to start service or not after performing some tasks, while I try to automate a process. Here is the example

```
sshpass -p$password ssh -T -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $srv <<EOF
if [cond1]
  then
    do task1
  else
    do task2
fi

some tasks to perform


## This part doesn't show up when run ##
read -p "Are you sure you want to start the service? Enter (Y/y or N/n)" -n 1 -r 
if [[ $REPLY =~ ^[Yy]$ ]]
  then
    start the service
fi

EOF
```

But when I run this automation script, It performs the previous tasks but skips the step for prompting the user for starting the service and skips that task too.

Please Help.

Thanks,
Sid

Comment: I know what's the problem, but not how to solve it. `read` wants to read from stdin which is filled by `<<EOF`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the way you invoke the script:

```
sshpass -p$password ssh -T -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $srv <<EOF
...
EOF
```

Here you are using stdin to send the script itself.  So where is `read` supposed to be reading from?  I actually don't have sshpass so I can't test this directly, but this works with ssh and a trusted key:

```
ssh <your ssh options> '
read -p "Are you sure you want to start the service? Enter (Y/y or N/n)" -n 1 -r
if [[ $REPLY =~ ^[Yy]$ ]]
  then
echo hi
fi
'
```

Now you are sending the script as a string leaving stdin free for interactive use.  I can't see all of your script, so this could cause other issues if your script is actually using the `'` in your script.

**Update**

You can avoid the single quote issue by saving the commands to a script file.  Let's say `a.sh`:

```
ssh <your ssh options> "$(< a.sh)"
```

This will send the command verbose into the ssh command without having to worry about variable expansion or anything.

**Update 2**

If we are trying to avoid saving the script to a file, you could still use the single quote option.  The way around the existing single quotes would be to change each occurrence to this: `'\''`.  So essentially it terminates the single-quoted string, adds a single quote to the string itself and then re-opens the single quote string.  Without a space in there, it is still all one string.  Here is an example if your read line used single-quotes instead of double quotes:

```
ssh <your ssh options> '
read -p '\''Are you sure you want to start the service? Enter (Y/y or N/n)'\'' -n 1 -r
if [[ $REPLY =~ ^[Yy]$ ]]
  then
echo hi
fi
'
```

Note how Stackoverflow's syntax highlighting parses this correctly and sort of illustrates what I was trying to say. I would translate as much of your single quotes to double quotes as you can to reduce complexity here.

You could also use double quotes instead of single quotes.  The issue now is that your string can be manipulated by the bash interpreter before it goes through ssh.  In order to avoid this, you will need to escape all expansions as well as existing double quotes.  Like this:

```
ssh <your ssh options> "
read -p \"Are you sure you want to start the service? Enter (Y/y or N/n)\" -n 1 -r
if [[ \$REPLY =~ ^[Yy]$ ]]
  then
echo hi
fi
"
```

Again, to avoid the complexity with this method, translate as many of your double quotes to single quotes as you can.

## **FINAL UPDATE**

You can use the original string as is using a combination of command substitution, cat and a here doc with no expansion:

```
ssh <your ssh options> "$(cat <<'EOF'
read -p "Are you sure you want to start the service? Enter (Y/y or N/n)" -n 1 -r
if [[ $REPLY =~ ^[Yy]$ ]]
  then
echo hi
fi
EOF
)"
```

Note that this method actually tricked Stackoverflow's syntax highlighting, but it works.

Comment: Hi Jason, thanks for the answer. Can we use any other character instead of ‘. My Scripts does use ‘ many a times which causes the script to end abruptly.

Comment: Thanks about that Jason. That certainly make sense. But can I do it without creating a.sh files?? Any way to do it directly??

Comment: @SiddharthGandhi I updated my answer again.  There really isn't a clean way to do it, but it is possible.

Comment: @SiddharthGandhi I actually found a practical way to do this... check out the FINAL UPDATE.